# What is the difference between Layers and Groups?

Tags: three.js

What exactly is the difference between [Layers](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Layers) and [Groups](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/objects/Group) in Three.js?

From my understanding, layers are good to control visibility and groups simply group objects such that they can be manipulated together. Is the following example correct usage?

- Six objects, A, B, C, D, E and F
- Create three groups, each containing a pair of objects. Group 1 holds A and B, group 2 holds C and D and group 3 holds E and F
- Create two layers, layer one containing A, C and E and layer 2 containing B, D and F

This way, if I understand it correctly, I can manipulate each pair as one with the groups and I can control which part of the pairs is shown (over all pairs) with layers.

Comment: With layers you can show/hide visibility of all objects within that layer. Like with Photoshop. With Group, you can add multiple child objects so you can move, rotate, & scale them as one.